# How to set a word in a string to keep changing according to a value?

Tags: java

Can someone tell me whats a java method similar to the python's format method where I could replace a variable ?holder in a string with my own ones?

for instance:

```
    t1 = "test"
    t2 = "example"
    "This is a {0} test {1}".format(t1, t2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at any of the `String` methods?

Answer (score 4):

You can format a string like this:

```
String t1 = "test1";
String t2 = "test2";
String.format("This is a %s test %s",  t1, t2);
```

You can have different symbols following the `%` sign, check this documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 3):

From Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

```
   // Explicit argument indices may be used to re-order output.
   formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
   // -> " d  c  b  a"
```

What does `%4$2s` mean?

- %: The start of Format String
- 4$: The 4th argument
- 2: Width of 2
- s: String

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.util.MesssageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

```
int planet = 7;
String event = "a disturbance in the Force";

String result = MessageFormat.format(
    "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
    planet, new Date(), event);
```

Comment: Daniel Gabriel's answer of using `String.format()` is even simpler and almost exactly like the Python version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class for that, but a far easier and less verbose way would to just use this code:

```
"This is a " + t1 + " test " + t2
```

If you need good formatting capabilities, you can use `String.format`:

```
String.format("This is a %s test %s", t1, t2);
```